# How can i import a db from SQL Server to Azure db?

Tags: sql-server, azure, window

I have a db in sql server 2014 and i am trying to deploy the database to Azure db using Tasks-> Deploy database to Azure SQL Database.
[image]

I installed DAC framework but still i am not able to. When i try to connect to my local Azure server from SQL Server i am able to connect to it.  Is there anything else that i am missing ?

Comment: Even though you SQL 2014, have you tried this using the latest version of SSMS (17.x)?

Comment: No, i haven't. Is this not possible using SQL 14 ?

Comment: Keep in mind that Azure SQL PaaS was quite immature in 2014 and I am not sure the corresponding SSMS client has been updated to suit. Try SSMS 17.X, it should do everything you need it to do for 14 and have a far better Azure capability.

Comment: Hi, i installed SSMS 17.9 and did the same and it was successful. There might be some compatibility issue with 14. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. I have posted the above as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that Azure SQL PaaS was quite immature in 2014.

Please upgrade your SSMS version to 17.x. This will work fine with your SQL 14 databases but have all the upgraded tooling for Azure SQL included.